# I have added custom domain mapping in cloud run with verified domain, but my domain is not getting active

Tags: google-cloud-sdk

I have added custom domain mapping in cloud run with verified domain, but my domain is not getting active.

I have deleted previous mapping then again added mapping, but it's still not activating